# Filter in RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

```
 class Transaction
 {
        int transactionId,transactionType,transactionStatus;
        double transactionAmount;
        Date transactionDate;    
}
```

I want to filter the list of transactions based on the combination  **Transaction** property using RxJava. Combination changes runtime so  someone can help me how to use **filter()** operator for the same

Comment: It isn't clear how exactly you want to filter these items, or what you have tried (and why that didn't work). Please explain in more detail (perhaps with an example) what you expect to happen and what you have tried.

Comment: @tanis i tried using filter operator but i was able to filter that list using one property but in my case user can select multiple filter like transaction amount range with transaction so on and i am using RxJava for the first time

Comment: You can call `filter()` as many times as you want to apply multiple filters, or you can make a single more complex filter that applies multiple filters in a more customized way.

Comment: But how can i call filter with combination of two property say amount and date if i am not wrong

Comment: Again, the easiest way would be to call `filter()` twice- the first time filter out the items with the amount you want, the second time filter out the items with the date you want.

Comment: Ok thank you so i will pass the result of first filter to second one and get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I had to do the same thing that you want to. I create a simple solution to handle multi filtering which looks like this:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void testSample() throws Exception {
        TransactionDatabase transactionDatabase = new TransactionDatabase();

        transactionDatabase.insert(new Transaction(1, 50.00, new Date()));
        transactionDatabase.insert(new Transaction(2, 20.00, new Date()));
        transactionDatabase.insert(new Transaction(3, 110.00, new Date()));
        transactionDatabase.insert(new Transaction(4, 250.00, new Date()));
        transactionDatabase.insert(new Transaction(5, 5.00, new Date()));
        transactionDatabase.insert(new Transaction(5, 73.00, new Date()));

        List<Func1<Transaction, Boolean>> filters = new ArrayList<>();

        filters.add(transaction -> transaction.transactionAmount > 20);
        filters.add(transaction -> transaction.transactionAmount < 100);

        transactionDatabase.getTransactions(filters)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private class Transaction {
        int transactionId;
        double transactionAmount;
        Date transactionDate;

        public Transaction(int transactionId, double transactionAmount, Date transactionDate) {
            this.transactionId = transactionId;
            this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
            this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Transaction{" +
                    "transactionId=" + transactionId +
                    ", transactionAmount=" + transactionAmount +
                    ", transactionDate=" + transactionDate +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class TransactionDatabase {
        List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

        public void insert(Transaction transaction) {
            transactions.add(transaction);
        }

        public Observable<Transaction> getTransactions(List<Func1<Transaction, Boolean>> filters) {
            Observable<Transaction> observable = Observable.from(transactions);

            for (Func1<Transaction, Boolean> filter : filters) {
                observable = observable.filter(filter);
            }

            return observable;
        }
    }
}
```

It will print this:

```
Transaction{transactionId=1, transactionAmount=50.0, transactionDate=Tue Jun 14 16:21:24 BRT 2016}
Transaction{transactionId=5, transactionAmount=73.0, transactionDate=Tue Jun 14 16:21:24 BRT 2016}
```

I think that it is a pretty solution for your problem.

Hope that it helps.

Best regards.